# NPM install of @mui/styles is not working for React 18

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to install [Material-UI Styles](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/) to a React project, but whenever I run this command in the terminal:

`npm i @mui/styles`

It reads the following message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: apollo-music-share@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"*" from the root project
```

And here's the code in React:

```
import { HeadsetTwoTone } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    title: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}))

const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <AppBar color="secondary" position="fixed">
            <Toolbar>
                <HeadsetTwoTone />
                <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" component="h1">
                    Apollo Music Share
                </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work because the package doesn't exist and it won't install. I searched on the web for a solution, but nothing seems to be working at this point.

Would anyone know how to get this going?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32982

Comment: Oh ok, I understand that it's now deprecated. I'm actually following Reed Barger's React Bootcamp course and his videos are a bit dated. In the code above, do you know how I would go about using "createTheme" and "ThemeProvider" to style the Typography component above? I'm pretty stuck and can't continue on with the course.

Answer (score 19):

`npm i @mui/styles --force`

it needs a different version of React, but actually it is fine to use React 18 (never actually tested it, but speaking from my experience with other packages that have the similar issue)

Comment: "⚠️ @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18." - https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/ It is intended to be used in React 17 to help assist in the transition from JSS to Emotion styling

Comment: you have to use the @mui/system because the @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18

Comment: This may not work as of Dec 2023 - force install can create other runtime errors like the one below (for me):
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
theme.spacing is not a function
TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function
    at http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:331:21...

Answer (score 3):

The Material UI (MUI) does not work on React 18.

You have to downgrade your React to 17.

To downgrade React to 17, run `npm install --save react@17.0.2` and `npm install --save react-dom@17.0.2`

This will work perfectly!

Comment: How does your answer help anyone you think, downgrading React?

Comment: This is the correct answer, as documented in the official MUI docs - https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

Comment: What has worked for me when using a template, is running 
{npm i --legacy-peer-deps}

Comment: @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18, instead you can use another style option not to downgrade react

Comment: No one wants something to "just work" people want to upgrade to use new features and/or get security patches... Please don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

@mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18

So now, you have two options:

1. use `@mui/system` - `sx` props for styling (https://mui.com/system/getting-started/overview/)
2. retry this command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following command:

```
npm i @mui/styles --save --force
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { HeadsetTwoTone } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <AppBar sx={{ color: "secondary", position: "fixed" }}>
      <Toolbar>
        <HeadsetTwoTone />
        <Typography sx={{ marginLeft: 2 }} variant="h6" component="h1">
          Apollo Music Share
        </Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

you can use sx function for same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).